# program to make a star pattern with a single for loop

Tags: java

I made the following program

```
public class StarPattern5 {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int j=1;
        for(int i=1;i<=15;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
            if(i==1 || i==3 || i==6 || i==10)
            {
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

it's printing

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

I want to optimize it so that we can print 50 lines without writing too much code.Thanx in advance..:)

Comment: do you want print upto 50-line for this pattern ?

Answer (score 3):

Just accumulate a string in the loop:

```
String s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
  System.out.println(s += "*");
}
```

or:

```
for (String s = "*"; s.length() <= 50; s += "*") {
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) class from the Apache common lang package like this:

```
public class StarPattern5 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        for(int i =1;i<=50;i++)
            System.out.println(StringUtils.repeat('*',i));
    }
}
```

This will preserve you from writing too much code but it uses a 3rd party library, it depends of what you exactly want/need.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a single loop variation that resets `i` to 0 if it reaches a variable called `count`.

```
public class star {
    public static void main(String...banana)
    {
        for (int i = 0, count = 1; i < 50; i++)
        {
            if (i == count)
            {
                count++;
                i = 0;
                System.out.println("");
            }
            System.out.print("*");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print such triangle using recursion with the same time complexity of 1 `for` loop as following:

```
public String printTriangle (int count) {
if( count <= 0 ) return "";

String p = printTriangle(count - 1);
p = p + "*";
System.out.println(p);

return p;
```

if you want to print triangle of 50 lines then pass the argument `count = 50`.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a Number : ");
        int num;
        num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        string design = null;
        ////////Forpatern 
        ///    *****
        ///    ****
        ///    ***
        ///    **
        ///    *
        ////----start----------
        for (int i = num; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (num != 1)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    num = num - 1;
                    //Console.WriteLine();
                    design = design + System.Environment.NewLine + ("*");
                    i = num;
                }
                else
                {
                    design = design + ("*");
                }
            }
        }
        //-----End
        int spaceCounter = 0;
        int Rows = num;
        ////////For patern 
        ///    *****
        ///     ****
        ///      ***
        ///       **
        ///        *
        ////----start----------
        for (int i=num;i>=0;i--)
        {
            if(spaceCounter==0)
            {
                if (i != 0)
                {
                    design = design + "*";
                }
                else {
                    num = num - 1;
                    i = Rows + 1;
                    spaceCounter = Rows - num;
                    design = design + System.Environment.NewLine;
                }
            }
            else if(spaceCounter>0){
                design = design + " ";
                spaceCounter = spaceCounter - 1;
            }
        }

        ///---------End
        Console.WriteLine(design);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: This code will print following pattern with in a single loop.
Pattern are following..

*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *

and second one is
****
***
**
*

you can remove one loop for check any one pattern

Answer (score -1):

It's so easy. Like this, you can make it by yourself

```
public class StarPattern5 {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StingBuilder("");
    for(int i =1;i<=50;i++){
        sb.append("*");
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Title says with a single for loop.

Answer (score -1):

#CPP Program for Print the dynamic pyramid pattern by using one loop in one line.

https://www.linkedin.com/posts/akashdarji8320_cpp-cplusplus-c-activity-6683972516999950336-ttlP

```cs
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int rows;
    
    cout<<"Enter number of rows :: ";
    cin>>rows;
    
    for( int i = 1, j = rows, k = rows; i <= rows*rows; i++ )
        if( i >= j && cout<<"*" && i % k == 0 && (j += rows-1) && cout<<endl || cout<<" " );
}
```

Comment: Read the question again: OP is using Java, not C++